# How to extract the substring for each column of a file in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, extract

Given a text file named file like this:

```
AAA 3/4 2/2 3/5 
BBB 3/4 2/3 3/3 6/7 
CCC 4/4 7/9
```

What should I do to get just the numerator of each fraction? like following:

```
AAA 3 2 2
BBB 3 2 3 6
CCC 4 7
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$> cat text
AAA 3/4 2/2 3/5 
BBB 3/4 2/3 3/3 6/7 
CCC 4/4 7/9
```

Idea is to match any fraction and get only numerator from each one. So, fraction is *(numbers)*`/`*(numbers)* . Using groups it's easy to get what you want.

```
$> sed -r -e 's/([0-9]*)\/([0-9]*)/\1/g' ./text
AAA 3 2 3 
BBB 3 2 3 6 
CCC 4 7
```

Comment: Why not just `sed 's!/[0-9]\{1,\}!!g' text`?

Comment: Just for readability. I'm not sure that OP is really familiar with `sed`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Thanks for replying. Actually I'm not familiar with `sed`, but I'll try to figure this one out..

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ Why didn't you put backslashes before parentheses? Like `sed -r -e 's/\([0-9]*\)\/\([0-9]*\)/\1/g' ./text`

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ also, what are '-r' and `-e` for here? Thanks.

Comment: There is no need in brackets escaping because of using `-r` option, which is equal to `--regexp-extended`. `-e` is not really necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\/[0-9]*//g' file
AAA 3 2 3 
BBB 3 2 3 6 
CCC 4 7
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This does work, but I don't quite understand the code. Could you explain a little bit?

Comment: This looks for multiples (the `g` flag) of a forward slash `\/` (which needs to quoted with a backward slash) followed by zero or more digits. `[0-9]*` and replaces them with nothing `//`

Answer (score -2):

Try using [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) or a [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) program.

Edit: Removing UUOC as per comments.